# How to get specific batch of rows of table using eloquent laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm making a chat app using laravel. There is a button in top of the chat box which if it is pressed the 30 last messages before the last previous messages in the box are loaded to the box. I know how to get 30 last messages `(take methode)` from table but don't know how do it for next 30 last messages.
Can anyone help me please?

This is Message table columns:

```
content | from_id | to_id | created_at | users_id
 ------- --------- ------- ------------ ---------
  hello |   39    |   12  |  7/6/2017  |  39:12
```

Comment: Last 30 messages based on what? `id`? `created_at`? `updated_at`? Basically, you'd have to adjust your query to know where to start and end, based off of the requirements, and limit the returned results to 30.

Comment: Based on created_at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i believe you can do this in laravel very easily

```
YourModel::paginate(30);
```

with this you can get data in paginated form and you dont have to use `take` method